# Boundary conditions at infinity for 1+2D wave equation in Mathematica 7

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions, boundary-condition-at-infinity, version-7

To solve a waves equation, I need to define some boundary conditions.  The wave is propagating on an infinite plane, and it's not a membrane fixed on some fixed support.  I'm have difficulties in setting up the proper conditions with this working code:

```
Tmax = 20;

WaveEquation = 
  D[Phi[t, x, y], t, t] - D[Phi[t, x, y], x, x] - D[Phi[t, x, y], y, y] == 0;

PHI0[x_, y_] = Tanh[x] - 1.5Exp[-0.25(x^2 + y^2)]; (* Initial field *)

BoundaryConditions = { (* The issue is here ! *)
   Phi[t, -10, y] == PHI0[-10, y],
   Phi[t, 10, y] == PHI0[10, y],
   Phi[t, x, -10] == PHI0[x, -10],
   Phi[t, x, 10] == PHI0[x, 10]
   };

InitialConditions = {
   Phi[0, x, y] == PHI0[x, y],
   (D[Phi[t, x, y], t]/.t -> 0) == 0
   };

WaveSolution = NDSolve[
   Flatten@{WaveEquation, InitialConditions, BoundaryConditions},
    Phi,
   {t, 0, Tmax},
   {x, -10, 10},
   {y, -10, 10},
   PrecisionGoal -> 2
   ];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate[Phi[t, x, y]/.WaveSolution/.t -> time],
  {x, -10, 10},
  {y, -10, 10},
  PlotPoints -> {20, 20},
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}},
  Axes -> True,
  MeshFunctions -> (#3&),
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  ImageSize -> 700,
  Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
  SphericalRegion -> True
  ],
 {time, 0, Tmax, 0.01}
 ]
```

By running this code, we could clearly see the waves reflections on the bounding box.  I want to get rid of that effect, since the wave is supposed to be propagating on an infinite plane.  What can I do here?  Take note that I'm working on **Mathematica 7.0**, so the option `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` isn't recognized by my version, and it would be inapropriate anyway since the waves would get back to the origin after a while.

So how can I tell Mathematica that there isn't any boundary to constraint the waves?

---

**EDIT1:** Is there a way to tell Mathematica that all waves should get truncated at the boundaries, without producing any reflections, creating something equivalent to a boundary at infinity?  My problem mainly comes from the **reflections** at the borders `{{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}` that I would like to prevent.

---

**EDIT2:** My question is similar to this one (but without an answer yet): [Absorbing/Derivative Boundary Conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192827/absorbing-derivative-boundary-conditions?rq=1)

Answer (score 7):

Aha, finally here comes a chance to share my implementation of 2nd order absorbing boundary condition (ABC). To understand why the b.c. is implemented in this way, one may refer to Chapter 6 of [Lloyd N. Trefethen, *Finite Difference and Spectral Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations*](http://129.67.184.129/trefethen/pdetext.html) <strike>but to be honest I myself don't understand the underlying math very well, either</strike>.

I've used [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) to discretize the PDE to a system of ODE because `NDSolve` cannot directly handle 2nd order ABC.

The code is tested in *v6.0.0* so should work in *v7*, too.

```
domain = {-10, 10}; tend = 20;

patt = x | y | t;
Table[{Numerator@
    Together@With[{theothervar = First@Complement[{x, y}, {var}]}, 
      var - PadeApproximant[#, {s, 0, {2, 0}}] & /@ 
        Simplify[var /. Solve[t^2 == x^2 + y^2, var] /. theothervar -> s t, t > 0] /. 
       s -> theothervar/t], var == Reverse@domain // Thread}\[Transpose], {var, {x, y}}]

bc = % /. {(var1 : patt) (var2 : patt) :> D[u[t, x, y], var1, var2], 
           (var : patt)^n_ :> D[u[t, x, y], {var, n}]}

With[{u = u[t, x, y]}, 
 ic = {D[u, t] == 0, u == Tanh[x] - 1.5 Exp[-0.25 (x^2 + y^2)]} /. t -> 0;
 eq = Piecewise[Flatten[bc, 1], D[u, t, t] - (D[u, x, x] + D[u, y, y])] == 0]

points = 50; difforder = 2;
grid = Rescale[Range@points, {1, points}, domain];

(*Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
  please find it in the link above.*)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, x, y], t, {grid, grid}, difforder];
ode = ptoofunc@Simplify`PWToUnitStep@eq;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;

sollst = Partition[
   NDSolve[{ode, odeic}, Flatten@Outer[u, grid, grid], {t, 0, tend}][[1, All, -1]], 
   points];

solfunc = rebuild[sollst, {grid, grid}]

Table[Plot3D[solfunc[t, x, y], {x, ##}, {y, ##}, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}] & @@ 
   domain, {t, 0, 20, 1/2}] // ListAnimate
```

[image]

P.S. For those in higher versions (At least `$VersionNumber>=10` I guess? ), the implementation of ABC and PML in the tutorial [Acoustics in the Time Domain](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html) may be a better choice.

Comment: It would be more useful if your code was complete, with the proper definitions included to run your code.

Comment: @Cham As mentioned above, definition of `pdetoode` can be found in the link. I don't want to include it in this post because it's still being updated and not short.