# Using Neumann boundary conditions for the wave equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, boundary-condition-at-infinity, wave-equation

I have the following code to solve the wave equation in 2D:

```
range=2;
trange=5;
region=Region[Rectangle[range{-1,-1},range{1,1}]];
wave2D = NDSolveValue[
      {D[u[t,x,y] ,{t,2}]- 
       Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
       u[0, x, y] == E^(-5 (x^2 + y^2)), 
       Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0
       (* absorbing condition *)
   },
   u, {t, 0, trange}, {x, y} \[Element] region] // Quiet;
```

I want to add an absorbing boundary condition: $\partial_t u=\partial_x u$ on the boundary and I think I have to use `NeumannValue` somehow but I don't understand the documentation of `NeumannValue`. Can someone show me how to do that and explain the idea behind `NeumannValue` in simple terms?

---

Edit: with the help of @Ulrich Neumann (perfect name for this question) I was able to make the following plot

```
plot = Table[
   Plot3D[wave2D[t, x, y], {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, 
    PlotRange -> {-.5, 1}, ImageSize -> 300], {t, 0, 3.8, .075}];
ListAnimate[plot]
```

[image]

Comment: The acoustics tutorials have ton of information on this. Have look there.

Comment: What should "Derivative[1, 0, 0][u] == 0" mean? A function needs arguments.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html) or [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AcousticPDEModels.html)

Comment: @DanielHuber Oops, I edited it now.

Comment: @user21 those are nice examples of how to use them but they don't really explain how NeumannValue works

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245309/1871 As to ABC, see also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236112/1871

Answer (score 4):

With `NeumannValue` the absorbing boundary conditions might be formulated for `x==2`and `x==-2`. Roughly  `NeumannValue` describes the flux perpendicular to the boundary:

```
    range = 2;
trange = 5;
region = Region[Rectangle[range {-1, -1}, range {1, 1}]];
wave2D = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], {t, 2}] - 
     Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 
    NeumannValue[-Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], x == 2]+NeumannValue[ -Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], x == -2], 
   u[0, x, y] == E^(-5 (x^2 + y^2)), 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0
   (*absorbing condition*)}, 
  u, {t, 0, trange}, {x, y} \[Element] region] 

Manipulate[Plot3D[wave2D[t, x, y], Element[{x, y}, region],PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {{t, 2 }, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I want it along all boundaries but that works by setting the predicate to true. What I still think is weird is that you don't need the term `laplacian u == 0` anymore, does NeumannValue evaluate to zero for the region that is not on the boundary?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion `Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}]`is still part of the pde!

Comment: I meant to say $\partial_{tt}u-\nabla^2 u=0$ does not occur on its own anymore, only in conjunction with NeumannValue, which would imply for me that NeumannValue evaluates to zero inside the bulk and to something else (in this case $\partial_t u$ on the boundary). It's still a bit confusing how it works but I guess it works now

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment above, the problem is related with (and essentially equivalent to, in my view) [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245309/1871), but let me elaborate with an answer anyway.

The explanation for the usage of `NeumannValue` can be found in **Details** section of document of [`NeumannValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html), and the tutorial [Finite Element Method Usage Tips](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) (Particularly **Formal Partial Differential Equations** and **`NeumannValue` and Formal Partial Differential Equations** section) but <strike>maybe</strike>probably a bit hard to follow. In short, the `NeumannValue` is defined based on a so-called **formal PDE**, which can be checked with the new-in-*12.2* `` NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE ``. (If you're not yet in *v12.2*, try the function in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/1871). )

Let's check the formal PDE corresponding to the 2D wave equation:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`;

{eqLHS, ic} = 
  With[{u = u[t, x, y]}, {D[u, {t, 2}] - 
     Laplacian[u, {x, y}], {u == E^(-5 (x^2 + y^2)), D[u, t] == 0} /. t -> 0}];

GetInactivePDE@
 First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eqLHS == 0, ic}, 
   u, {t, 0, trange}, {x, y} ∈ region]
```

[image]

As mentioned in **Details** section of document of `NeumannValue`:

> $∇·(-c ∇u-α u+γ)+…=f+\text{NeumannValue}[g-q u,\text{pred}]$ is used to specify the flux over the part of the boundary $∂Ω$ where pred is true, such that $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{n}·(c ∇u+α u-γ)=g-q u$ holds.

Clearly, in our case $-c ∇u-α u+γ=$`-{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]`.

Next step is to determine the $g-q u$. For $x=2$, the needed 1st order ABC is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$, $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{n}=(1,0)$, so

```
{1, 0} . (-(-{{1, 0}, {0, 1}} . Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}])) == gMinuspu
```

should be equivalent to

```
With[{u = u[t, x, y]}, D[u, t] + D[u, x] == 0]
```

at $x=2$. Then it's clear `gminuspu` i.e. $g-pu$ should be `-D[u[t, x, y], t]` at $x=2$.

Similarly we'll find at all the boundary of the rectangle region, the needed $g-pu$ terms are all `-D[u[t, x, y], t]`. So the needed `NeumannValue` is

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqLHS == NeumannValue[-D[u[t, x, y], t], True], ic}, 
   u, {t, 0, trange}, {x, y} ∈ region];

plot = Table[
  DensityPlot[sol[t, x, y], {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, 
   PlotRange -> {-.5, 1}, ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 50], {t, 0, 3.8, .075}];
ListAnimate[plot]
```

[image]

From the animation we can see the reflection is still somewhat obvious, this is expected because we're using 1st order ABC. To reduce the reflection, you may consider 2nd order ABC as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236112/1871). Setting up PML as shown in the tutorial [Acoustics in the Time Domain](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html#82427960) is also a possible choice.

Comment: (+1) do you have suggestions for how to improve the documentation to get rid of the 'probaby hard to follow'?

Comment: @user21 One thing I can think of is, perhaps the document should emphasize a bit more about the importance of **formal PDE/Inactive PDE**. Adding example showing how to determine the `NeumannValue` with the help of `GetInactivePDE` (for certain _strange_ PDE) may improve the readability of document, too. As we've seen, checking the corresponding formal PDE is almost unavoidable for setting `NeumannValue` correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I added some more information to the documentation. I feel that at the end of the day one has to think through the derivation of the FEM like it is hinted add in the NeumannValue ref page or the FEM tutorials to really understand the meaning of NeumannValue and how to use that. I am not sure there is really a short cut. But again, I tried to add more information to the documentation and made GetInactivePDE more prominent in conjunction with the sections on understanding PDE parsing and NeumannValue.