# System of PDEs with coupled Neumann BC--how to use NeumannValue?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I have the following system of PDEs for functions $u_1,u_2$ in a region $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$:
$$
\begin{cases}
2\partial_{xx}u_1+\partial_{yy}u_1+\partial_{xy}u_2-u_1=f_1 & (x,y)\in\Omega\\
\partial_{xx}u_2+2\partial_{yy}u_2+\partial_{xy}u_1-u_2=f_2 & (x,y)\in\Omega\\
\nu\cdot\nabla u_1=\nu_x-\nu\cdot\partial_x(u_1,u_2) & (x,y)\in\partial\Omega\\
\nu\cdot\nabla u_2=\nu_y-\nu\cdot\partial_y(u_1,u_2) & (x,y)\in\partial\Omega,
\end{cases}
$$
where $f_1,f_2$ are known functions on $\Omega$ and $\nu$ is the outward unit normal to the boundary $\partial\Omega$.

I am interested in solving this problem numerically using Mathematica for generic $f_1,$ $f_2,$ and $\Omega$, but for ease of presentation, I here is my attempt at a solution when $f_1(x,y)=x$, $f_2(x,y)=y$, and $\Omega$ is the unit disk:

```
lhs1 = 2 D[u1[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u1[x, y], {y, 2}] + D[u2[x, y], x, y] - u1[x, y];
lhs2 = 2 D[u2[x, y], {y, 2}] + D[u2[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u1[x, y], x, y] - u2[x, y];
f1 = x;
f2 = y;
bc1 = NeumannValue[x - {x, y} . D[{u1[x, y], u2[x, y]}, x], True];
bc2 = NeumannValue[y - {x, y} . D[{u1[x, y], u2[x, y]}, y], True];
NDSolveValue[{lhs1 == f1 + bc1, lhs2 == f2 + bc2}, {u1,u2}, {x,y} \[Element] Disk[]];
```

Mathematica doesn't seem to like derivatives appearing in Nuemann boundary values; it gives the error:

```
NDSolve::fembcdepderiv: Derivatives of dependent variables in boundary conditions are not supported with the Finite Element Method in this version of NDSolve.
```

I do not see an analytical way to decouple the Neumann boundary conditions or transform the boundary conditions to no longer include derivatives on the right hand side. Are there any numerical workarounds?

Comment: You misunderstand the usage of `NeumannValue`. It's not because the Neumann value is coupled, it's because `Derivative` cannot appear inside `NeumannValue`, see discussions in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/224815/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267744/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245309/1871 But sadly knowing the correct usage of `NeumannValue` isn't enough to resolve the problem, because there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to express your b.c. as legal `NeumannValue`.

Comment: @xzczd Right, that is the root of the problem. My understanding $u_1$ and $u_2$ can appear in `NeumannValue` but not their derivatives.

Comment: Just to confirm, $\nu_x=x,\ \nu_y=y$, right?

Comment: @xzczd In the case that $\Omega$ is the unit disk, yes.